# How to describe this language a* (ba (cf* (g ( f +h )* bf* )* e )* a* )* in words?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I was task to describe this regular expression a* (ba (cf* (g  ( f +h )*   bf*   )*  e )*  a)* informally.

**My attempt at describing it informally** =  any number of a followed by any number of one b one a with any number of one c and any number of f with any number of one g with any number of f or h one b and any number of f and one e and one or more a.

I know it's wrong but I don't know what else to write. I'm just really confused

**Question** : What is the informal description of this language?

Comment: I think the informal description would be "a mess".

Comment: I think so too. I don't think its possible to make it sound logical.